# Unable to access Plesk panel from Leaseweb Dedicated Server

Tags: dedicated-server

I have purchased a dedicated server from Leaseweb, package included plesk control panel but I could not figure out how to access it from my web-browser? I have tried http://ipaddress:8443 and also http://ipaddress:8880

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `https` instead of `http`. Port 8443 is the correct default port. Also make sure that Leaseweb actually installed and activated Plesk on your server. It might be something you still need to do by yourself, but they just provide you with a license.

So if https doesn't do it, you'd best contact Leaseweb about this issue, they'll probably be able to help you better.

Comment: They re-installed everything, works swiftly now